# Filtering a list of Objects with lists- Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, javascript-objects

What would be the most effective to filter a list that has objects with lists in them. I have been looking at underscore's _.filter function but this takes takes arrays and returns arrays.

I want to take an object and filter the it by a certain word.

For example, how would I filter:

```
    [
{level: "Title 1", details: [
    {real: "There we go", fake: "THERE_WE_GO"},
    {real: "Where is it", fake: "WHERE_IS_IT"},
    {real: "The dog jumped", fake: "THE_DOG_JUMPED"},
] }, 
{level: "Title 2", details: [
    {real: "There it is", fake: "THERE_IT_IS"},
    {real: "Car is flying", fake: "CAR_IS_FLYING"},
    {real: "Driving is fun", fake: "DRIVING_IS_FUN"}
] }, 
{level: "Title 2", details: [
    {real: "There he is", fake: "THERE_WE_GO"},
    {real: "Where is the dog", fake: "WHERE_IS_THE_DOG"},
    {real: "The dog died", fake: "THE_DOG_DIED"},
    {real: "I am tired", fake: "I_AM_TIRED"},

]}
];
```

by the word "the"

such that it returns

```
    [
{level: "Title 1", details: [
    {real: "There we go", fake: "THERE_WE_GO"},
    {real: "The dog jumped", fake: "THE_DOG_JUMPED"},
] }, 
{level: "Title 2", details: [
    {real: "There it is", fake: "THERE_IT_IS"},
] }, 
{level: "Title 2", details: [
    {real: "There he is", fake: "THERE_WE_GO"},
    {real: "Where is the dog", fake: "WHERE_IS_THE_DOG"},
    {real: "The dog died", fake: "THE_DOG_DIED"},
]}
];
```

Notice that when filter by the word "the" I also want to keep anything that has the word "the" as a part of it, such "There"...and I only went to check if the word "the" is in the "real" index of the objects inside the detail's array.

Comment: That is not an object, but rather an array of objects.  As such, the underscore filtering just work just fine for you. You of course need to write the filtering function.  Have you made any attempts for which you can show code?

Comment: There is a built–in [*filter*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20) in ES5, why do you need underscore.js for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`, but you will have to apply it once on each of the inner lists and once on the outer list:

```
var phrase = "the".toUpperCase();
return _.filter(_.map(data, function(item) {
    return {
        level: item.level,
        details: _.filter(item.details, function(detail) {
            return detail.fake.indexOf(phrase) > -1;
        })
    };
}), function(item) {
    return item.details.length > 0;
});
```

From your example I cannot infer whether you need the outer `filter` at all, or whether you would not want to drop items with an empty details list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with plain javascript:

```
    var arr = [
    {level: "Title 1", details: [
        {real: "There we go", fake: "THERE_WE_GO"},
        {real: "Where is it", fake: "WHERE_IS_IT"},
        {real: "The dog jumped", fake: "THE_DOG_JUMPED"},
    ] },
    {level: "Title 2", details: [
        {real: "There it is", fake: "THERE_IT_IS"},
        {real: "Car is flying", fake: "CAR_IS_FLYING"},
        {real: "Driving is fun", fake: "DRIVING_IS_FUN"}
    ] },
    {level: "Title 3", details: [
        {real: "There he is", fake: "THERE_WE_GO"},
        {real: "Where is the dog", fake: "WHERE_IS_THE_DOG"},
        {real: "The dog died", fake: "THE_DOG_DIED"},
        {real: "I am tired", fake: "I_AM_TIRED"},

    ]}
];
function filterArr(arr, str) {
    var ret = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; arr[i]; i++) {
        var obj = arr[i].details;
        ret[i] = new Object();
        ret[i]['level'] = arr[i].level;
        ret[i]['details'] = [];

        for (var j = 0; obj[j]; j++) {
            if (obj[j].real.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) != -1) {

                ret[i].details.push(obj[j]);
            }


        }
    }
    return ret;
}
console.log( filterArr(arr, 'the'));
```

Comment: You can replace 3 lines with 1 using `ret[i] = {level:arr[i].level, details:[]};`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another "plain" javascript solution. It tries to minimse hard coded properties, but likely that's not really necessary.

You can do it in less code using *filter*, *forEach*, *map*, etc. but generally plain loops run faster than nested iterators:

```
  function filterOn(data, value) {
    var re = new RegExp(value,'i');
    var result = [];
    var details, keys, obj, temp;

    for (var i=0, iLen=data.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      temp = {level: data[i].level, details:[]};
      details = data[i].details;

      for (var j=0, jLen=details.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        obj = details[j];

        for (var p in obj) {

          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && re.test(obj[p])) {
            temp.details.push(details[j]);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (temp.details.length) result.push(temp);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: why breaking in the third for loop?